# Inline html 5 for Cordova Android...no video but plays sound

Tags: android, css, cordova, video

I am trying to get my html 5 video to play inline in my Cordova application. Currently, it works fine in iOS. I am using the "webkit-playsinline" attribute with no success.

I am hearing only the sound from the video, but the video does not show up. Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: does your video have a size?